# How to enable text compression on Amazon Affiliate iframes?

Tags: wordpress, iframe, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I am trying to optimize a Wordpress site that has some Amazon Affiliate iframes on it. Those iframes are those that you can get on the left corner of Amazon -> Obtain link -> Text + Image when you are on a specific product to obtain an affiliate link of it:

[image]

and this is how they look like (as typical Amazon affiliates iframe):

[image]

My question comes because when I run a test on PageSpeed, it shows me "Enable text compression" error that makes references to all the urls from the iframes:

[image]

My hosting have CPanel so I have enabled Text Compression on cPanel --> Optimize Website -->  Mark "Compress All Content" option but it is still showing the error, so it doesnt seem it takes any effect on them.

Is there a way to optimize those iframes and enable text compression on them? It is a bit annoying that it takes so much time to load all of them (and they are between 15-20).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add lazy load to your Iframe to increase page speed.
Refer this link to implement lazy load for iframes in Wordpress
https://web.dev/iframe-lazy-loading/#wordpress

```
<iframe 
loading = "lazy"
style="width:120px;
height:240px;" 
marginwidth="0" 
marginheight="0" 
scrolling="no" 
frameborder="0" 
src= {amazon link}>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you! Making them load on lazy load almost fix the error! Now, iframes that are not being shown on the first load does not give the error but for those that are loading on the first load of the page, PageSpeeds still shows the `Enable text compression` error. I guess that PageSpeeds does not mark "lazy" iframes with this error because it would not affect now on the loading page process but... is there any way to fix the error on those iframes that are still loading? Thank you!

Comment: If you still want to increase your pagespeed you have to use compression techniques like Gzip or Brotli. But both these compression techniques are for js , cs and html files. I don't think we cant implement it on Iframes

Comment: If above code helps Please mark it as Answer :)

Comment: Yes, @Ashendale pointed it out, that the compression could not be done because it is done on the server side so it's not possible to compress files hosted outside. And ofc, I will mark it as accepted one if nobody adds any answer that fix the totality of the iframes.

Comment: Hi Hari E, I have marked your question and give the bounty because your answer helped to me to solve almost 100% of the iframes error. I would like to fix the 100% but well... its a good improve. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thanks for marking this as a answer. If i find any other ways to improve it,  i will add another answer here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since compression takes place on the server side it's not possible to compress files hosted outside of your server and that is why you can't serve the files from the Amazon iframe compressed. Also the iframes may cause problems with any caching on the website.

Maybe an alternative would be to create the product box yourself and then link them to the product using the affiliate link instead?

Old answer:

What version of apache are you running?

I belive if it's above version 2 then you could try adding this to your root .htaccess. 
 Try it out and see if the compression takes any effect on the iframes.

```
# BEGIN GZIP
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                      "application/javascript" \
                                      "application/json" \
                                      "application/ld+json" \
                                      "application/manifest+json" \
                                      "application/rdf+xml" \
                                      "application/rss+xml" \
                                      "application/schema+json" \
                                      "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                      "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                      "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                      "application/x-javascript" \
                                      "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                      "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                      "application/xml" \
                                      "font/eot" \
                                      "font/opentype" \
                                      "image/bmp" \
                                      "image/svg+xml" \
                                      "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                      "image/x-icon" \
                                      "text/cache-manifest" \
                                      "text/css" \
                                      "text/html" \
                                      "text/javascript" \
                                      "text/plain" \
                                      "text/vcard" \
                                      "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
                                      "text/vtt" \
                                      "text/x-component" \
                                      "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
                                      "text/xml"
    
</IfModule>
# END GZIP
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! I have added the code that you have suggested on the root .htaccess of my wordpress site but it does not fix the error. I have `Apache 2.4.54`.

Comment: My idea was that there could be a problem with the compression settings on the server side and instead adding the compression to the htaccess would fix it. Too bad it didn't work.
What I do know is that you should be able to compress the text from an iframe using deflate/gzip so I'm wondering what else could be causing the problem.
I'll do some more digging and get back to you if I can find a solution. :)

Comment: And it's only the iframe that is not getting any compression right?
Have you tried testing the site on https://www.giftofspeed.com/gzip-test/ for example? That way we can rule out any other error :) I know for example that sometimes It's needed to restart the server after activating compression. @FranciscoRomero

Comment: I guess that what you were trying to do is to simulate via htaccess the intended behaviour of cPanel when `Compress All Content` is selected, right?

Comment: Exactly, that was my Idea atleast. I thought it could be worth a shot :)

Comment: @FranciscoRomero I actually found this piece of information "Some optimizations like browser caching and GZIP compression can only be applied to files hosted on your server. You cannot control resources that are hosted on other servers." Which means I was wrong and you actually can't compress the iframes from Amazon which makes sense when I think about it. When I tried it out I was hosting my own iframe and ofcourse that worked. Sorry that I gave you some missinformation!

Comment: That makes sense about why it did not work with Amazon iframes, because the widget is loaded from its server (from `https://ws-eu.assoc-amazon.com/widgets/...` url). What I am wondering is that a company like Amazon does not optimize this kind of stuff that would make sites that have their urls faster, so they will get more traffic. I expect it will be a solution to solve this :/ Thank you for all your help!!

Comment: Yup it's very strange that a huge company like Amazon won't serve their affiliate iframe information compressed. I have an idea that maybe they can't check the browser information through the iframe and can't tell if the browser supports compression or not and maybe that is why they serve it uncompressed to everyone instead? Could be why... But it's just a hunch. No worries, glad I could help a little bit at least. :)

Comment: That would have sense, that they do not want to risk about innecesary "errors" about compression but I do not want to think that there is no option to optimize that. I know that there are plugins that avoid it because they use the API and does not use the iframe, but you need at least 3 sales/month to get access to the API (if Im not wrong).

Comment: Ashendale I finally marked @Hari E answer as the accepted one and give to him the bounty because with his solution I have fixed almost 100% of the error. I give to you an upvote because you also helped me to clarify about text compression. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Happy you eventually found a solution!  Thanks for the upvote.